# Android Studio: How to have multiple buttons auto-flow in a layout?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

My app has 7 buttons that I want to "auto-align" on the screen, depending on screen size.

So on a phone, the layout might look like this...

```
[button 1] [button 2] [button 3]
[a really long button number 4]
[button 5] [btn 6] [btn 7]
```

...but on a tablet, all 7 buttons would be on a single line (or maybe the last 2 buttons would be on the next line).

```
[button 1] [button 2] [button 3] [a really long button number 4] [button 5] [btn 6] [btn 7]
```

I've tried using a RelativeLayout but can't quite get it to work.
I could use 3 LinearLayouts and just accept there will always be 3 rows of buttons but that isn't very elegant.

Is there a way to get this effect?
I've search quite a bit but everything I've found is mostly related to button clicks which is not the issue.
Any help is appreciated! :)

**EDIT**

After more research, I agree Fragments are overall the best solution so I'm accepting that answer.

However for this particular app, I decided to use a HorizontalScrollView which takes up the least amount of UI real estate. Below is the markup for my solution...

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <!-- ### all 7 buttons here; only showing one for brevity -->
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) would be of good use here.

Essentially you would define a particular fragment(or 'part of a view') for the specific screen densities you want them tied to.

For a phone you could define a fragment `button_phone_fragment.xml`.

For a tablet you could define a fragment `button_tablet_fragment.xml`.

You would then inflate the layout in your code:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_phone_fragment, container, false);
```

[Here is](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) some more information surrounding replacing fragments between one another.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something called "grid layout". Two most important properties for you would be "columnSpan" and "layout_row"

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="3"
android:rowCount="3"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.inducesmile.gridlayouttutorial.MainActivity" >
<Space />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:text="@string/button_name" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:text="@string/button_name" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="@string/button_name" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:text="@string/button_name" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:text="@string/button_name" />
```

Writing this code on my smartphone, might seem a bit messy :)